# Unix time conversion returning random numbers

Tags: c, function, time

I have a bit of code for calculating when did the previous full moon happen.

```
int humanreadable(seconds){
  time_t now=seconds;
    struct tm ts;
    char buf[80];
    ts = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y %m %d", &ts); 
    printf("%s\n", buf);        // Works correctly, returns "2016 12 14", not needed, only used to for a check
    int prevY = &ts.tm_year+1900;
    int prevM = &ts.tm_mon+1;
    int prevD = &ts.tm_mday;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", prevY,prevM,prevD); // Does not work, returns random numbers
    //later add return prevY/prevM/prevD pointers so I can pass them on
return 0;
}

int prevFullMoon ( int y, int m, int d){  // int * prevY, int * prevM, int * prevD){//temporarely disabled pointers, later need to add them back so assert in main works
  if(valid_date(y,m,d)==INVALID_DATE){
    return valid_date(y,m,d);
  }
  int tmp=epoch(y,m,d);
  while (isFullMoonEpochCheck(tmp)!=1) {
   tmp=tmp-ONE_DAY;
  }
  humanreadable(tmp);
  return 1;
}

int main ( int argc, char * argv [] )
{
  prevFullMoon( 2017, 1, 11);       //temporary code to check what it is returning
  //assert ( prevFullMoon ( 2017, 1, 11, &y, &m, &d ) == 1 && y == 2016 && m == 12 && d == 14 ); //this needs to pass
}
```

I have a problem that my "humanreadable" function does not print the year, month and day i need it to. When I print the "buf" variable, it returns the date correctly but I need the date in three separete variables so I can pass them on from "prevFullMoon" function.

If you read my comments in the code you should get the idea of what is happening and what I am trying to achieve.

I am pretty lost when it comes to structures and pointers so any help is appreciated.

PS.  In this thread I am mainly want to know why my time conversion is not working but if you are willing to help me out with the pointers and passing the prevY,prevM and prevD, I would appreciate that.

Thank you

Comment: The onus of figuring out what you want and the *specific* nature of your problem is on you, not the reader.

Comment: `struct tm ts; ....  int prevY = &ts.tm_year+1900;` should have raised a warning and save you a post on SO.  Enable your compiler warnings and save time.

Comment: 2nd tip: "function does not print the year, month and day i need" and `ts = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(...` are 2 functions that first should have had their return values checked.

Comment: This cannot even compile unless you've got a horribly broken compiler. :F Or something that defaults to 28 years old C standard. The compiler is required to spit out at 5 diagnostics messages for this, but I don't see them in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there are more issues because you didn show the implementation of `validDate`, but start fixing those problems adding to an address:

```
int prevY = &ts.tm_year+1900;
int prevM = &ts.tm_mon+1;
int prevD = &ts.tm_mday;
```

should be

```
int prevY = ts.tm_year+1900;
int prevM = ts.tm_mon+1;
int prevD = ts.tm_mday;
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked. This just shows that I still have a lot to learn, such a stupid mistake. Thank you very much. PS. validDate is kinda borked too but that is a different story. (Most of it works, just the detection if the days are correct is not right). But whatever, I will hopefully figure it out (or make a different thread about it).